# Unable to sudo python but I can python without sudo

Tags: python, linux, rhel

I'm performing some maintenance on my linux box (rhel via ssh) but when I go to run a python script as such:

> ```
> asemani$ python3.6 get-pip.py
> ```

```
  File "get-pip.py", line 20061, in <module>
    main()
  File "get-pip.py", line 194, in main
    bootstrap(tmpdir=tmpdir)
  File "get-pip.py", line 82, in bootstrap
    import pip
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 646, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 616, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "/tmp/tmp04ft8p5f/pip.zip/pip/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 646, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 616, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "/tmp/tmp04ft8p5f/pip.zip/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 646, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 616, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "/tmp/tmp04ft8p5f/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3018, in <module>
  File "/tmp/tmp04ft8p5f/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3004, in _call_aside
  File "/tmp/tmp04ft8p5f/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3031, in _initialize_master_working_set
  File "/tmp/tmp04ft8p5f/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 651, in _build_master
  File "/tmp/tmp04ft8p5f/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 644, in __init__
  File "/tmp/tmp04ft8p5f/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 700, in add_entry
  File "/tmp/tmp04ft8p5f/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2017, in find_on_path
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools-28.8.0.dist-info'
```

When I try to use sudo:

```
asemani$ sudo python3.6 get-pip.py'
[sudo] password for asemani: 
sudo: python3.6: command not found
```

Python isn't recognized? What is going on? How can I use sudo on python3.6. I'm pretty sure I installed it correctly.

*Edit:*

**Approach 1:**

```
[asemani@746c9prda5r asemani]$ sudo -E python3.6 get-pip.py
sudo: python3.6: command not found
```

**Approach 2:**

```
[asemani@746c9prda5r asemani]$ sudo /usr/local/bin/python3.6 get-pip.py 
[sudo] password for asemani: 
Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f0c4b78d908>, 'Connection to pypi.python.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/pip/
^COperation cancelled by user
```

Comment: try `sudo -E python3.6 get-pip.py`

Comment: @Dalvenjia You mean `-E`? `-e` does the same as `sudoedit`.

Comment: updated question

Answer (score 2):

It looks like sudo is losing your PATH from the environment, you need to pass the full path to python3.6:

```
which python3.6
```

Which will give you the full path, e.g. `/opt/bin/python3.6`

Then you need to do

```
sudo /opt/bin/python3.6 get-pip.py
```

Comment: I'm getting a timeout error, I've updated my question to show this

Answer (score 0):

Must be python path is not set in PATH env variable:
Try to follow below steps:

search for paths where python is installed

**ls -lrth /usr/local/bin/python3.5**

-rwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 12M Mar 22 15:55 /usr/local/bin/python3.5

1)Add python path

**vim ~/.bash_profile**

**PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin/python3.5**

**export PATH**

2)Open new session (putty or any other fav.)

3)**whereis python**

4)Should work now or you can directly execute program

**/usr/local/bin/python3.5 mydemo1.py**